# Combining 2 SQL queries into 1

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have a complex (for me) query that I can't seem to get right.  I can get the data I'm looking for separately but need to combine them in same query.  I am not looking to use a view or a temp table.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE AS PSTANDARDPRICE
FROM PRODUCT_T, USES_T
WHERE PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTID = USES_T.PRODUCTID
```

This query returns:

PSTANDARDPRICE

175

200

200

750

Then I do:

```
Select uses_t.productid, sum(rawmaterial_t.materialstandardprice*uses_t.quantityrequired) AS TOTALRAWMATERIALCOST
From rawmaterial_t, uses_t
Where rawmaterial_t.materialid = uses_t.materialid
Group by uses_t.productid
order by productid
```

This query returns:

PRODUCTID   TOTALRAWMATERIALCOST

1                   120

2                   62.4

3                    307.2

I'm looking for:

[image]

I've tried to use a sub query, I've tried to use a Join with the two queries and I've tried a UNION in desperation.

This gets me close but TOTALRAWCOSTPERPRODUCT is the same for every row which is incorrect

```
SELECT PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTID, PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE AS PSTANDARDPRICE, TOTALRAWCOSTPERPRODUCT 
 FROM (
Select uses_t.productid, sum(rawmaterial_t.materialstandardprice*uses_t.quantityrequired) AS TOTALRAWCOSTPERPRODUCT
From rawmaterial_t, uses_t
Where rawmaterial_t.materialid = uses_t.materialid
Group by uses_t.productid
), PRODUCT_T, USES_T
WHERE PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTID = USES_T.PRODUCTID
```

How can I get to where I need to be?

Comment: You could simply add the Product_T table to the second query along with it's WHERE clause, query for that PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE column and add it to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Also, you should consider rewriting that query as to use INNER JOINs, for readability. Good examples on that on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Yea, I've been looking at a lot of examples.  I'm just not having any luck bridging the gaps.

Comment: You should rewrite you question then, showing the schema for the three tables and posting a small sample of data for each one, instead of just showing the expected query return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    uses_t.productid,
    PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE AS PSTANDARDPRICE,
    sum(rawmaterial_t.materialstandardprice*uses_t.quantityrequired) AS TOTALRAWMATERIALCOST
FROM
    uses_t
    INNER JOIN rawmaterial_t
        ON rawmaterial_t.materialid = uses_t.materialid
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT_T
        ON PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTID = USES_T.PRODUCTID
GROPUP BY
    uses_t.productid,
    PRODUCT_T.PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE
ORDER BY
    uses_t.productid
```

Comment: Thanks!  Much cleaner than my solution.  I don't think I considered more than one inner join.  This is very helpful, thank you again

Comment: NOt knowing the data, it is possible that there might be some uses that do not have records in one or more of the other tables. Caonsider at least testing that with left joins and see if you get teh same number of records. YOu may still want the inner joins if you want to exclude those, but it is something that you should be aware of.